# Why is the controller's parameterless constructor called and not the one with the biggest number of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have had a website asp.net MVC solution

My controller had 2 constructors: one parameterless and one with few parameter.

The code used to go through the ctor with the parameters, injection them with DI using Unity container.

I have merged my website into another one.

Now my controller is initialized via the parameterless ctor.

What am I missing?
My code:

The initializer code is executed.

```
public static class Initializer
{
    private static bool isInitialize;
    private static readonly object LockObj = new object();
    private static IUnityContainer defaultContainer = new UnityContainer();

    static Initializer()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (isInitialize)
            return;

        lock (LockObj)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = defaultContainer;

            //registering Unity for web API
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
            //registering Unity for MVC
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            container.RegisterType<ICritieriaLoader, CritieriaLoader>();
            container.RegisterType<IAppsLoader, AppsLoader>();
            container.RegisterType<ISaveTestToBD, SaveTestToDB>();
            container.RegisterType<ITestOperations, TestOperations>();


            container.RegisterType<IServicesManager, ServicesManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IMamConfigurationManager, MamConfigurationsManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IAppsDataManager, AppsDataManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IMamConfiguration_V1Manager, MamConfiguration_V1Manager>();
            container.RegisterType<ICtidProd_V1Manager, CtidProd_V1Manager>();
            container.RegisterType<ICtidsAliasManager, CtidsAliasManager>();


            container.RegisterType<IDalFactory, DalFactory>();
            container.RegisterType<IDal<AppsDataBl>, AppsDataDal>();
            container.RegisterType<IApplicationLogger, Log4NetLogger>();
            container.RegisterType<IDal<MamConfigurationBL>, MamConfigurationBlDal>();
            container.RegisterType<IDal<Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.MamConfiguration>, MamConfigurationDal>();
            container.RegisterType<IDal<AddServiceBL>, NewService>();


            container.RegisterType<IAlias_V1UiToEfConvertor, Alias_V1UiToEfConvertor>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor, MamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ICtidProdValidator, CtidPRodValidator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IGeoProdValidator, GeoProdValidator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IConstListsProvider, ConstListsProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IEntityToUiConvertor, EntityToUiConvertor>();

            if (!isInitialize)
            {
                isInitialize = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Log.Application.Warn("Application started", "Application started");

        WebApiConfig.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Initializer.Initialize();
```

.

```
[Authorize]
public class CtidProdController : SAPController
{

    #region Members

    private IApplicationLogger mApplicationLog { get; set; }

    //private IMamConfiguration_V1Manager mMamConfigurationManager { get; set; }

    private ICritieriaLoader mCritieriaLoader { get; set; }

    private IAppsLoader mAppsLoder { get; set; }

    private IMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor mMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor { get; set; }

    private CtidProdModel mCtidProdModel { get; set; }

    private IConstListsProvider mConstListsProvider { get; set; }

    private ICtidProd_V1Manager mCtidProd_V1Manager { get; set; }

    private ICtidsAliasManager mCtidsAliasManager { get; set; }


    #endregion


    #region CTOR

    public CtidProdController()
    {

    }


    public CtidProdController(IApplicationLogger logger, ICtidProd_V1Manager ctidProd_V1Manager,
        ICritieriaLoader critieriaLoader, IAppsLoader appsLoder, IMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor mamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor,
        IConstListsProvider constListsProvider, ICtidsAliasManager ctidsAliasManager)
    {
        mApplicationLog = logger;

        mCtidProd_V1Manager = ctidProd_V1Manager;

        mCritieriaLoader = critieriaLoader;

        mAppsLoder = appsLoder;

        mMamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor = mamConfiguration_V1UiToEfConvertor;

        mConstListsProvider = constListsProvider;

        mCtidsAliasManager = ctidsAliasManager;

        FillModel(mConstListsProvider);
    } 

    #endregion
    }
```

The new website code: The injection code:

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    private IResolutionRoot resolver;

    internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        IDisposable disposable = resolver as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();

        resolver = null;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

        return resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

        return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}

public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectDependencyScope(kernel.BeginBlock());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you add some code snippets ?

Comment: Sounds like your DI is not able to resolve all of the parameters in the constructor so it is hitting the constructor it can resolve (0 params). Post some code.

Comment: @DarrenDavies added some code

Comment: Just curious why the first code snippet is using Unity while the last code snippet appears to be using Ninject?

Comment: @Tuzo, as I said. Merged two different projects.

Answer (score 0):

like Darren Davies pointed you are maybe missing some attributes. Unity takes by default in fact the constructor with the most parameters, but to be sure if you have more than one ctor, you should decorate the desired one with the [InjectionConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650802.aspx) attribute!
Hope this helps.
Kind regards

Comment: Did your CtidProdController class inherited the SAPController class before the merge too?

Comment: No. How do you think that might be related?